# How to create side panel (Windows runtime 8.1)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to create side panel with additional information about user. I found something similar in Skype (https://www.dropbox.com/s/oarrtvykbat9eh4/screen.png). This panel appears when user click on his profile photo.
What i should to use? Flyouts? May be in winrt has something  of the box?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a custom `Settings Flyout`.

A `Settings Flyout` can be created via

> Your Project > Add > New Item > Settings Flyout

[image]

You can find a detailed tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh872190.aspx#complete_code_examples).